# How to return text between map looping in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to return text between map looping in React Native. i want to show the result like this:

```
Project A
  Team 1
  Team 2

 Project B
  Team 3
  Team 4
```

this is my source:

```
renderData(){
  return this.state.teams.map(i => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{marginTop: 8,}}>{i.project}</Text>
    </View>
  )
  return i.users.map(j =>{
    return(
      <View>
        <Text style={{marginTop: 8,}}>{j.name}</Text>
      </View>   
    )
  });
});
}
```

and this is the JSON data:

```
"teams": [
   {
     "project": "projectA"
     "users":[
        {"name":"Team 1"},
        {"name":"Team 2"}
     ]
    },
    {
     "project": "projectB"
     "users":[
        {"name":"Team 3"},
        {"name":"Team 4"}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

the source still does not work, how the solution?. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second return seems to be unreachable code. I think this should work.

```
renderData(){
  return this.state.teams.map(i => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{marginTop: 8,}}>{i.project}</Text>
        {
          i.users.map(j => {
              return(
                <View>
                  <Text style={{marginTop: 8,}}>{j.name}</Text>
                </View>   
              )
            });
         }
      </View>
    );
  });
}
```